# rowspan の css. 親の親を参照したい

Tags: html, css, sass

`tr > td[rowspan]` に隣接する `tr > td` にスタイルを当てたいときに、どのように指定すればいいのか分かりません。

```
<tr>
  <th colspan="3"> あああ </th>
  <td> いいい </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> ううう </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> えええ </td>
</tr>
```

このような場合に、`<td> ううう </td>`　および `<td> えええ </td>` に対してスタイルを当てたいです。

Comment: 「隣接する」という言葉の定義が曖昧に思います。具体的にコードを提示いただき、どの箇所にスタイルを適応したいのかご提示下さい。

Comment: <tr>
<th colspan="3"> あああ </th>
<td> いいい </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> ううう </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> えええ </td>
</tr>

このような場合に、
<td> ううう </td>　および
<td> えええ </td>
に対してスタイルを当てたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS4の擬似クラス`has`を使えば実装できますが、まだ未対応のブラウザも多い状態です。
対応環境なら以下の記述で反映されるはずです。

```
tr:has(th[colspan]) ~ tr{ color: red;}
```

Answer (score -1):

以下でOK。
td:only-child { background-color: pink;}

実装としては、他のtableへの影響がない様に、
.hoge td:only-child { background-color: pink;}
とした方がいい。

追記1：例示されているhtmlがcolspanになっているのはrowspanですよね？
追記2：質問のタイトルに「親の親を参照したい」とありますが、目的が『 ううう 　および  えええ  に対してスタイルを当てたい』のでしたら、「親の親を参照」する必要はなく、td:only-childで目的を果たせる、という意図で回答しました。